# Vector of numbers in angle parameter of element_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2, vector, tidyverse, angle

Is there any way to include a vector of numerics within the `angle` parameter of the element_text() function in R. It appears that in a new version of ggplot2, the `angle` parameter only accepts a single number.

[image]

Comment: Yes you can put a vector there, but whatever behaviour follows now is unsupported so susceptible to change in the future.

Comment: Works ok here using ggplot2 3.3.5: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(gear), mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = c(45,0, 90), size = 20))`.  Do you have particular scenario where not working?

Comment: @JonSpring The vector in angle parameter was working for me till I updated to R version 4.2.0